# How many 3 digit numbers have no zeros, how many have no zeros or fives...

Tags: combinatorics

How many 3-digit numbers have no zeros? How many 3-digit numbers have no zeros and no fives? How many 3-digit numbers have no zeros but at least one five?

I'm just really confused on how to do this. I figured the first was 729 and the second was 512 but I'm very stuck on the third one.

Comment: You are mostly done.  Just note that if you remove the zero and five-free numbers from the zero-free numbers, the numbers left over must have no zeroes and at least one five.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

For the third case let start from case 1 and subtract the number of cases without 0 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

*Hints*

1) How many 3-digits numbers at all ? How many of them have zeroes ? How can you get your answer using this information?

2)The same idea there are 900 3-digits numbers at all. How many numbers of them have $0$ or $5$ in representation?

3)First digit isn't $0$ assume that first one is $5$ , then how many numbers with no zero digits you have?
The same idea if you have $5$ at second position , e.t.c. *But* don't forget about numbers you may count twice!